# Allegro 5 C++ Memory leaks with map of ALLEGRO_BITMAP pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management, memory-leaks, allegro5

I'm making a game in C++ using Visual Studio 2017 and Allegro 5. When I check for memory leaks using  `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`, I currently find two leaks when launching my game and then closing from the title screen. More leaks happen when I go past the title screen, but I want to fix these first in case they're related. I have traced the leak to a line after my main game loop: `ImageLoader::get_instance().unload_content()`. When I set a breakpoint for the memory allocation at the location of the leak, I see this call stack:

```
Game1.exe!operator new(unsigned int size) Line 19
Game1.exe!std::_Allocate(unsigned int _Count, unsigned int _Sz, bool _Try_aligned_allocation) Line 87
...
Game1.exe!ImageLoader::ImageLoader() Line 5 
Game1.exe!ImageLoader::get_instance() Line 17   
Game1.exe!main() Line 103
```

Line 5 of ImageLoader is `image_map = std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, ALLEGRO_BITMAP*>()`. Image map is declared as in ImageLoader.h like so: `std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, ALLEGRO_BITMAP*> image_map`. `ImageLoader::get_instance()` is a static method returning an ImageLoader instance:

```
ImageLoader & ImageLoader::get_instance()
{
static ImageLoader loader;
return loader;
}
```

The only place I currently create an ImageLoader instance is in the `unload_content()` call I mentioned before, where the leak is coming from. (Obviously this means the call is unnecessary in this specific case, but I have tested calling `get_instance()` sooner and the same problem occurs as a result of the static ImageLoader object being created. In either case, I see the same two memory leaks.) Although the creation of `image_map` seems to be the source of the leak, it is empty the entire time the program is running. What is the correct way to deallocate the memory reserved for the map?

EDIT:

Here is the `unload_content` method in which I attempt to deallocate the memory for the image map:

```
void ImageLoader::unload_content()
{
for (auto const &it : image_map) {
    al_destroy_bitmap(it.second);
}
```

The way my program is currently set up, no elements are inserted into the map-- the only instance of an ImageLoader created is in the line `ImageLoader::get_instance().unload_content()`. While my game does have a main loop, I never call `ImageLoader::get_instance()` or any other function from ImageLoader within the loop.

EDIT 2:

Here is the context of the `unload_content()` call, after my main game loop:

```
{
    ImageLoader::get_instance().unload_content();
    ScreenManager::get_instance().unload_content();
    al_destroy_display(display);
    al_destroy_timer(timer);
    al_destroy_event_queue(event_queue);
}
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
return 0;
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the map and not the objects pointed to by your `ALLEGRO_BITMAP*` pointers? Because this is a map of `ALLEGRO_BITMAP*`s, not of `ALLEGRO_BITMAP`s (contrary to the claim in your question title). Present your [MCVE].

Comment: "What is the correct way to deallocate the memory reserved for the map" Let the `map` go out of scope, but if it is a member variable of a object spawned by a Meyers Singleton, it's not going out of scope any time soon.

Comment: If using a singleton means that the member variable will not go out of scope, does that mean the memory leaks are unavoidable? I used `unload_content()` rather than a destructor because it seemed like the destructor wasn't being called, but as I understand it, this doesn't solve the problem.